# SQL Server query empty xml element value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

I had empty instance that was breaking the query

```
...
<publicationreference>
  ...
  <referencedpublicationid />
```

Before query contained :

```
reference.value(
  './referencedpublicationid[1]','uniqueidentifier') 
  AS [referencedpublicationid],
```

resulting in error.

After fix query contained :

```
reference.value(
  '(./Field[@fieldName="referencedpublicationid"]/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') 
  AS [referencedpublicationid],
```

resulting in `<referencedpublicationid xsi:nil="true" />`

Can someone explain how does those lines differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your two queries are against different XML sources. In the first you have `referencedpublicationid` as a element name and in the second you have it as an attribute called `@fieldName`. I also have a hard time understanding what the resulting XML has to do with this. `xsi:nil="true"` is generated when you create XML using `for xml path, elements xsinil`.

I will instead try to address what I think is the issue you see.

Try this code:

```sql
declare @XML xml = '<referencedpublicationid />'
select @XML.value('./referencedpublicationid[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
select @XML.value('(./referencedpublicationid/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
```

The first query returns an empty string and the second returns `NULL`.

If you instead specify the data type `uniqueidentifier` the first will fail because you can not cast an empty string to uniqueidentifier. The second converts fine since it is `NULL`.

All values in untyped XML in SQL Server are strings that is then converted to the specified data type in the values function.

When you use `./referencedpublicationid[1]` you will get back the concatenated value of all sub text() values. SQL Server for some reason gives you an empty string when there are no `text()` nodes to be found.

This expression `(./referencedpublicationid/text())[1]` specifies the first `text()` node in referencedpublicationid and since there are none you get the result of `NULL`.